# reverse the join command

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, webforms

I am taking over a project written with asp.net VB and im using mssql.

I have a text box which has the text value of the facility (FacName)

What I would like to do is when the user clicks submit, the program takes the text entered in the text box, looks up the facilities table, finds the facility name, matches the facility ID with it and, and updates the Episode facility ID column.

Here are my two tables:

```
Episode                   Facilities

ID__________FacilityID   |   ID__________FacName
1___________10           |   10__________Beenleigh
2___________14           |   14__________Sunnybank
3___________15           |   15__________Brisbane
```

The user updates the episode to point to a different facility - Lets say they want Episode.ID '2' to reference a new facilility, in this case, 'Brisbane'

They input Brisbane in the text box and hit submit, and the results in the episode table become:

```
Episode                   Facilities

ID__________FacilityID   |   ID__________FacName
1___________10           |   10__________Beenleigh
2___________15           |   14__________Sunnybank
3___________15           |   15__________Brisbane
```

So its kind of doing a lookup in the facilities table and returning the Facilities.id and using that value in the episode.FacilityID column

I have gotten my select statement to work well, which hopefully will help anyone itching to answer my question!

The **working select statement**:

```
 SELECT Episode.ID, Episode.NOCSID, Episode.Disease, Episode.PHUID,     
        Episode.Status, Episode.Date, Episode.PersonID, Episode.ChangeType, 
        Episode.ChangeBy, Episode.ChangeDate, Episode.DoctorID, 
        Episode.FacilityID, Episode.OnsetDate, Episode.CloseDate, 
        Episode.Duplicate, Episode.OutbreakID, Episode.ClinicalLead, 
        Episode.NextActionDate, Facilities.FacName, Facilities.ID AS Expr1 
        FROM Episode 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Facilities 
        ON Episode.FacilityID = Facilities.ID WHERE (Episode.ID = @ID)
```

The **not working UPDATE** statement:

```
UPDATE Episode
SET NOCSID = @NOCSID,
    Disease = @Disease,
    PHUID = @PHUID,
    Status = @Status,
    PersonID = @PersonID,
    ChangeType = 'Updated',
    ChangeBy = @ChangeBy,
    ChangeDate = GETDATE(),
    DoctorID = @DoctorID,
    OnsetDate = @OnsetDate,
    CloseDate = @CloseDate,
    Duplicate = @Duplicate,
    OutbreakID = @OutbreakID,
    ClinicalLead = @ClinicalLead,
    NextActionDate = @NextActionDate,
    FacilityID = @FacilityID
FROM Episode
INNER JOIN Facilities
  ON Episode.FacilityID = Facilities.FacName
WHERE (Episode.ID = @original_ID)
AND (Episode.NOCSID = @original_NOCSID
OR Episode.NOCSID IS NULL
AND @original_NOCSID IS NULL)
AND (Episode.Disease = @original_Disease)
AND (Episode.PHUID = @original_PHUID)
AND (Episode.Status = @original_Status)
AND (Episode.PersonID = @original_PersonID
OR Episode.PersonID IS NULL
AND @original_PersonID IS NULL)
AND (Episode.DoctorID = @original_DoctorID
OR Episode.DoctorID IS NULL
AND @original_DoctorID IS NULL)
AND (Episode.FacilityID = @original_FacilityID
OR Episode.FacilityID IS NULL
AND @original_FacilityID IS NULL)
AND (Episode.OnsetDate = @original_OnsetDate
OR Episode.OnsetDate IS NULL
AND @original_OnsetDate IS NULL)
AND (Episode.CloseDate = @original_CloseDate
OR Episode.CloseDate IS NULL
AND @original_CloseDate IS NULL)
AND (Episode.Duplicate = @original_Duplicate
OR Episode.Duplicate IS NULL
AND @original_Duplicate IS NULL)
AND (Episode.OutbreakID = @original_OutbreakID
OR Episode.OutbreakID IS NULL
AND @original_OutbreakID IS NULL)
AND (Episode.ClinicalLead = @original_ClinicalLead
OR Episode.ClinicalLead IS NULL
AND @original_ClinicalLead IS NULL)
AND (Episode.NextActionDate = @original_NextActionDate
OR Episode.NextActionDate IS NULL
AND @original_NextActionDate IS NULL)
```

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you're asking.  The way I'm reading this, it sounds like you want to update the foreign key (Episode.FacilityID).  Is this a typo?

Comment: Why don't you just use a DropDownList? Do you want to create new facilities if they don't exist based upon user-input?

Comment: Dustin - I want it to search the Facility table by the FacName column, get the matching ID, and update the Episode table FacilityID column. I actually have a jquery drop down list based on user input. The previous revision used a drop down but it was pulling in thousands of results - too much for the user to sort through.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fdb1c/16 for any interested I have put the query here. Its working except that its updating every record in the FacilityID column

Comment: I'm still confused on what you want - in your first example you have a join on the select statement Episode.FacilityID = Facilities.ID, and your update join statement says Episode.FacilityID = Facilities.FacName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so here is what I ended up doing:

Becuase I was using a jquery drop down list that also used a ashx handler, I had the Facility names I needed, I just needed the ID names so I could post the ID back to the database upon submit. So I modded the sql command to pull in the ID as well as the facility name like so:

```
  Public Class Search_VB : Implements IHttpHandler

Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    Dim prefixText As String = context.Request.QueryString("q")
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager _
            .ConnectionStrings("CDI").ConnectionString
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
    cmd.CommandText = ("select ID, FacName from Facilities where FacName like '%' + @SearchText + '%'")


    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText)
    cmd.Connection = conn
    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder

    conn.Open()
    Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While sdr.Read
        sb.Append(sdr("FacName") & (" ID: "))
        sb.Append(sdr("ID")).Append(Environment.NewLine)


    End While
    conn.Close()
    context.Response.Write(sb.ToString)

End Sub
```

[the drop down list showing facility id's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEBbZ.png)
So now I had my facility id, i needed to grab the Facility id ready for post-back.

So I updated the following in the script tag for the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //the code below gets the jquery drop down working, and uses the ashx handler to feed it results to populate the list
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[id$=txt_Search]').autocomplete('/Facility_Search.ashx');


        //monitor for when the user clicks the update button.
        $("[id$=Button1]").click(function () {

            //fetch the selected value from the text box
            FacNameTextValue = $('[id$=txt_Search]').val()
            //pull off the prefix (the facility name, leaving only the characters after the : character, this should
            //only leave the facility ID
            FacNameTextValue = FacNameTextValue.substring(FacNameTextValue.indexOf(":") + 2);
            //Filter everything out except numbers
            FacNameTextValue = FacNameTextValue.replace(/\D/g, '');
            // Now if the string is empty, we need to alert the user that no Facility match was found, and they need to create a new one.


            //Now populate the text box with the filtered facility ID
            document.getElementsByName('DetailsViewEpisodeEdit$FacilityIDTextBox')[0].value = FacNameTextValue;
            //alert is for debug purposes bellow, comment out when the code is working :)
            //alert(":" + FacNameTextValue + ":");

            //now check the string, and if we are left with nothing, then alert the user that the record will be left blank
            if (FacNameTextValue.length < 1) {
                alert("No matching facilility was found, facility field will be left blank.")
            }







        });

    });
</script>
```

So there you have it. Hope this helps. Im sure this is a really lateral way of doing it. If you have any suggestions/improvements, let me know!